# Django - trouble linking to new posts

Tags: django

I have searched far and wide, picking up tidbits of code along the way but the trouble is different tidbits may not be translating into a cohesive representation of what I want. Basically I have a page where I can create new blog posts at `/progresstracker/new` which, when I click submit I want the new post to be available at `/progresstracker/<category>/<slug>` and I have a landing page at `/progresstracker` which should have summaries of all the posts and links to the appropriate `/<category>/<slug>` URL. I think the issue is with the `pk`/`slug` but there could be several errors realistically.

## url:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^progresstracker/(?P<category>[\w\s]+),(?P<slug>[\w\s]+)/$', views.pt_detail, name='pt_detail'),
    url(r'^progresstracker/new/$', views.progresstracker_new, name='progresstracker_new'),
    url(r'^progresstracker/(?P<category>[\w\s]+),(?P<slug>[\w\s]+)/edit/$', views.post_edit, name='post_edit'),
    url(r'^progresstracker/', views.progresstracker, name='progresstracker'),
]
```

## views:

```
def pt_detail(request, slug):
    ptpost = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'blog/pt_detail.html', {'ptpost': ptpost})

def progresstracker(request):
    posts = Post.objects.order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/progresstracker.html', {'posts': posts})

def progresstracker_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            ptpost = form.save(commit=False)
            ptpost.author = request.user
            ptpost.published_date = timezone.now()
            ptpost.save()
            return redirect('pt_detail', slug=ptpost.slug)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})

def post_edit(request, slug):
    ptpost = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=ptpost)
        if form.is_valid():
            ptpost = form.save(commit=False)
            ptpost.author = request.user
            ptpost.published_date = timezone.now()
            ptpost.save()
            return redirect('pt_detail', slug=ptpost.slug)
    else:
        form = PostForm(instance=ptpost)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

## model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    posted = models.DateField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('books.Category')
    ...     
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/%s/%s/" % (self.category.slug, self.slug)
```

I don't have the template code with me now but "progresstracker.html" with the summary of all posts somewhat properly links to "progresstracker/(with %20 as spaces)/"

Comment: can you show us your method which is generating your slug ?

Comment: what exactly is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: I have getting a range of errors but don't have my laptop with me so can't give you specifics besides it's telling me that when I click a link to /progresstracker/<category>/<slug> it tells me nothing exists (ie when I create a new post it's not going to the right place).

Comment: I am getting a NoReverseMatch error at /progresstracker/new:Reverse for 'pt_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'slug': u'please-work'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['progresstracker/(?P<slug>[\\w\\s]+)/$']